# Ruby threads cannot be used in RubyCocoa without patches to the Ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-cocoa

I found this error in Ruby console while I am testing a Rails application.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib /mongrel.rb:285:  
in `run': Ruby threads cannot be used in RubyCocoa without patches to the Ruby interpreter
```

So I guess I have to patch or re-install RubyCocoa. But I don't found any content to do this. or you may have the better way to solve this?

This is my environment:

- ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.3
- Mac OSX 10.6

Comment: I think it might be due to the fact that Ruby prior to 1.9 uses green thread as opposed to native (kernel) threads. Have you tried upgrading to Ruby 1.9? or use other VMs like Rubinius or MacRuby.

Answer (score 2):

As Matthew points out in his answer, it may be a plug-in that is causing this. He found that [attachment_fu](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu) is one cause. (It can use Core Image for its image processing.) Creating a file in `config/initializers` (for a Rails application) with this line will silence the warning, at the expense of requiring one of the other image processors:

```
Technoweenie::AttachmentFu.default_processors.delete('CoreImage')
```

This isn't a problem for me; I deploy to non-Mac servers, and since those can't use CoreImage, I want to run the same thing during development anyway.

If you look at `/System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/
objc/ruby_addition.rb`, this is at the bottom of the file:

```
class Thread
  class << self
    alias :pre_rubycocoa_new :new

    # Override Thread.new to prevent threads being created if there isn't 
    # runtime support for it
    def new(*args,&block)
      unless defined? @_rubycocoa_threads_allowed then
        # If user has explicilty disabled thread support, also disable the 
        # check (for debugging/testing only)
        @_rubycocoa_threads_allowed = ENV['RUBYCOCOA_THREAD_HOOK_DISABLE'] || 
          OSX::RBRuntime.isRubyThreadingSupported?
      end
      if !@_rubycocoa_threads_allowed then
        warn "#{caller[0]}: Ruby threads cannot be used in RubyCocoa without patches to the Ruby interpreter"
      end
      pre_rubycocoa_new(*args,&block)
    end
  end
end
```

So for starters, we get a warning, but then it proceeds to call the original `Thread.new` anyway. I don't believe this warning is a real problem. It's just annoying to see it constantly in the console.

If you want to track down what's pulling in the monkey patch to `Thread`, grep for something that pulls in `osx/cocoa`:

```
$ irb
>> Thread.new { puts 'hi' }
hi=> #<Thread:0x1011328e0 run>
>> require 'osx/cocoa'

=> true
>> Thread.new { puts 'hi' }
(irb):3:in `irb_binding': Ruby threads cannot be used in RubyCocoa without patches to the Ruby interpreter
hi=> #<Thread:0x103bf76e8 run>
```

Comment: Assuming one wanted to actually fix the problem, how would one go about patching?  Or is there a different version to get for osx?  Or what?

Comment: [MacRuby](http://macruby.org) supplanted RubyCocoa, so I'd try that first. If this is still an issue, get in touch with the MacRuby developers.

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack:

```
$ RUBYCOCOA_THREAD_HOOK_DISABLE=1 ./script/server --debugger
```

Different quick hack:

```
$ echo "ENV['RUBYCOCOA_THREAD_HOOK_DISABLE']='1'" > config/initializers/disable_rubycocoa_warning.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not mongrel that is pulling it in but some plugin in your rails application. For me attachment_fu was the culprit

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. attachment_fu is installed in the application I see this warning in, as well. I'm not sure it actually uses it, so I'm going to look into removing the plug-in.